# Dynamically adding tabs to ViewPager with animation

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Ive been looking around for quite a while but i cannot seem to find anything about this.

Would it be possible to animate adding a new tab to the viewpager?

I am able to add a new fragment to my pagerAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() to dynamically add of remove view from the TabLayout. However, I bet it would look much better if its animated.

1. Is this possible?
2. What apProach would be recommended for this?